# On ios mobile device, embed youtube video (with iframe api) dont show the pause/play button overlay in the middle of the video while playing inline

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

this is a new behavior that started lately (last 2 months) in IOS mobile devices only. in android devices the pause/play button overlay still exists.

The behavior: 
when embedding inline youtube video with controls=0, when the video plays, the only way to stop it is by clicking the middle of the video on the pause button overlay (except using an external button and the api off course). in desktop and android this works great but in IOS the pause button overlay in the middle of the video does not exists any more. this means that in order to give the user the ability to stop the video we must put controls=1 which is less convenient.
is this intended or a bug?

also, the property fs=0 (is to allow full screen) does not work on IOS.

Thanks

Comment: After reading this, I immediately tested on iPhone 6 and Redmi Note 4 and it is true indeed, in Android the iframe is loaded and plays the video in that particular div / section / width while in iPhone it opens as if `it's another player` and has different pause button, theoretically speaking even iframe API wouldn't be able to pause or stop video, I know because I tried iframe API to play video (autoplay)